# What's the difference between Unless I do and Unless I did?

Tags: subjunctives

For Example:

> You won't see him again, unless you **get** to there (Another Country)
>
> You won't see him again, unless you **got** to there (Another Country)

Some people mentioned that **Subjunctive Mood** in sentence 2. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the difference between present and past (or in this case really a future hypothetical) tense.

Also, unless you are specifying the name of the country, you don't need to use "to". (I'd also omit the comma.)

The two correct sentences would be:

> You **won't** see him again unless you **get** there.
>
> You **wouldn't** see him again unless you **got** there.